# Оптимизация метода, который принимает много аргументов

Tags: c#

Есть два метода, которые создают и обновляют сущность в БД.

```
public void Create(int termOfSaleId, decimal firstPayment, decimal percentPayment, int numAmount,
                       int objectId, int roomNumber, int objectTypeId, DateTime firstPaymentDate,
                       DateTime contractDate,
                       int birja, string currencyName, decimal discount, decimal discountPercent, decimal secondPay,
                       decimal secondPayPercent, string designName, string course, string installmentTypeName,
                       decimal addition,
                       decimal additionPercent, bool installmentCheck, decimal derivative, decimal property,
                       bool additionPercentPriority, bool discountPercentPriority, bool firstPaymentPercentPriority,
                       bool secondPaymentPercentPriority, int firstPaymentDelay, string[] options, string note,
                       List<ClientsInfo> clients, DateTime? forwardContractDate, bool converted = false,
                       int? responsibleUserId = null, bool derivativeCalculation = true)

 public void Update(int id, int termOfSaleId, decimal firstPayment, decimal percentPayment,
                       int numAmount, int objectId, int roomNumber, int objectTypeId, DateTime firstPaymentDate,
                       DateTime contractDate,
                       int birja, string currencyName, decimal discount, decimal discountPercent, decimal secondPay,
                       decimal secondPayPercent, string designName, string course, int paymentStep,
                       string installmentTypeName,
                       decimal addition, decimal additionPercent, bool installmentCheck, decimal derivative,
                       decimal property,
                       bool additionPercentPriority, bool discountPercentPriority, bool firstPaymentPercentPriority,
                       bool secondPaymentPercentPriority, int firstPaymentDelay, int clientId, string[] options,
                       string note, List<ClientsInfo> clients, bool derivativeCalculation = true)
```

Может есть какие-то правильные варианты, используя которые можно уменьшить кол-во параметров передаваемых в объект? Я думал над использованием кастомного класа например DataRequest который будет в себе держать эти поля, и в случае добавления дового поля мы по фатку создадим новое свойство в этом класе, и допишем строку кода в методы Create и Update, но я не знаю, правильно ли это будет.

Comment: Да, нужно убрать их все в класс, возможно даже Create и Update тоже в этот класс убрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое правильное- это разбить всю это портянку параметров логически сгруппированные классы/структуры.

На сколько я помню, этой проблемы касаются в книге "Совершенный код" и приводят точно такое же решение.

Comment: В принципе такой вариант мне нравится, но есть ли вообще хоть какая-то альтернатива? За книгу спасибо, я посмотрю.

Comment: @Takeshi8059 . Ну... в качестве альтернативы можно иметь Dictionary<string,object>, заполнять его и передавать в методы и по ключу получать нужный аргумент с последующим его приведением. Но тут нету безопасности типов. Можно кортежи Tuple использовать. В какой-то редакции языка разрешили даже имена задавать элементам.

Comment: @Takeshi8059 в JavaScript практикуются, например, основные параметры описать отдельными параметрами, а все дополнительные параметры складывать в объект options.